# How to tuning Linux performance when run queue latency too big?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, performance

I observed that when system loading is rising, the run queue latency is about 10000 usecs. The application starts 8 JVM instances and each instance starts lots of threads and the platform is Linux.

I wonder if any general idea about tuning the run queue latency for such multi-thread application?

Comment: +1, because I don't understand why people are downvoting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A run queue latency of 10 ms is not that high.  The simplest thing to do is to reduce the number of threads you have attempting to run, or give the system more hardware (or more than one box) Ideally you want to have less busy threads than the number of cores you have.  There is only so much Linux can do if you have lots of threads which want to run efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The average latency is 10ms, but the latency often exceeds 20ms. Do you mean there is nothing can do when the hardware is fixed and the application can't be changed?

Comment: Not unless you have tuned the OS to be wildly different to the default settings. e.g. You could have increased the Nagle time to something very high which is causing a delay.  The cause of your delay is most likely what your application does, how it does it and to some degree what hardware you are using.  If you can't change the cause of your delay, tweaking around the edges won't help much (unless you have it very wrong in the first place)

Comment: Our computer is NUMA based, which have 80 cores (160 logical CPU when HT enabled) and the GC time is only about 1%. We want to push the performance to the limit. After I tried various performance tuning tools, I only found that the run queue latency may reveal some opportunity.

Comment: There are plenty of cores by the sounds of things.  This suggests each task is taking on average 10 ms and up to 20 ms to perform. i.e. it's not due to load on your machine being too high.  If your latencies were < 100 micro-seconds I would suggest getting a kernel bypass network adpater e.g. Solarflare, but you are unlikely to notice the difference.  Tuning your program is the real answer here.

Comment: BTW: I have written services which have a round trip latency of around 1 micro-second (between processes on the same machine) without needing to tune the OS.  The difference you can make is likely to be less than a micro-second if your kernel is reasonably configured already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When we run 20 tasks parallelly, we only see about average 300 usecs run queue latency. After scale up to 40 tasks. The average run queue latencies were to up 10 ~ 20ms. The application has nothing to do with disk IO and networking, it's a totally CPU intensive application. Any chances to improve the performance by config kernel?

Comment: That is quite a jump in latencies.  You would need to analyse the program (even if you can't change it) to see what resource is the bottle neck.  If the resource is manage by the OS, you have some chance of configuring it.  If it's not a system resource, you have to tune the application. The queue length and latencies are a *symtom* that a shared resource is being over used.  BTW: WHat is your NUMA layout? Is it possible you have 20 cores in one NUMA region i.e. does your machine have 4 NUMA regions?

Comment: Yes, we have 20 cores in one NUMA region, and we have 8 NUMA regions. We already use numactl to bind one JVM instance to each NUMA region, so I think it's not the problem.

Comment: I was going to suggest it appears that each JVM is only running across 20 threads at a time, and when you have more than 20 you get contention for those threads.  I would suggest trying to running the JVM across two NUMA regions and see if the jump up in latencies is better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Run queue latency depends on the the ratio of runnable (ready-to-run) threads to available CPUs.

When there is more runnable threads than available CPUs, i.e. when load averages are above the number of CPUs, inevitably some of the threads will have to wait until a CPU becomes available, i.e. till some of the other threads are blocked or preempted.

Thus, in order to improve run queue latency you either need to increase the number of available CPUs or lower the number of threads competing for the CPUs.

There is going to be more competition for CPU if the application is CPU intensive. You should investigate whether your JVMs aren't spending too much time doing garbage collection. When running multiple JVMs on a machine with few CPUs, you can easily increase the long tail of run queue latency by having many JVMs doing garbage collection at the same time. If this is the case, you can try increasing the number of threads and lowering the number of separate JVMs.